# Gatsby dynamic routes: 404 instead of component, can't configure

Tags: reactjs, routes, gatsby

I made a simple site with Gatsby.js and can't configure dynamic routes.

I have index.js page (was automatically created by react), that looks like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
const IndexPage = () => {

  return (
      <Layout
        pageTitle="Home Page"
      >
       Some text for my main page
      </Layout>
  )
}

export const Head = () => <title>Home Page</title>

export default IndexPage
```

Layout components includes Header that looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const Header = () => { 

  return (
    <Wrapper style={{ *some styles* }}>
     <Link to="/">Index</Link>
     <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link >
   </Wrapper>
)
};

export default Header;
```

I have my Projects page that looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import Layout from '../layout'

const Projects = () => {

return (

<BrowserRouter>
      <Layout>
           <Wrapper>
               <Routes>
                    <Route path="projects/:projectID/" component={ProjectDetails} />
                </Routes>
                 <MyProjectLink to="/projects/1"> 
                     Project 1
                 </MyProjectLink>
                    <MyProjectLink to="/projects/2">
                     Project 2
                   </MyProjectLink>
             </Wrapper>
        </Layout>
</BrowserRouter>
)

}

export const Head = () => <title>Our Projects</title>

export default Projects
```

And I have my ProjectDetails component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

import Layout from '../../pages/layout';

const ProjectDetails = () => {

    const { projectID } = useParams();

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Wrapper>
                <h2>Project {projectID}</h2>
            </Wrapper>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default ProjectDetails;
```

The problem is that when I navigate to localhost:8000/projects/1 (or "2", or "3", or "100500") I see a 404 page instead of my ProjectDetails component.

I've tried wrapping the index page to BrowserRouter and move the routes with my route there, but that's a dumb idea in my opinion (and it doesnt work).

Did I miss something? Some features of Gatsby (v5) that I don't know about? I'm new to Getsby and to be honest I thought that dynamic routes here work the same way as in React Router.

Comment: How are you creating the pages (projects)? Are you trying to create client-only routes or just a template for projects?

Comment: That's all I did for now: create template component.

It seems to me I have to create markdowns for these pages and then make some configuring with createPage in gatsby-node, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gatsby extends its routing from React, however, the way to create routes is slightly different.

As far as I understand your code, you are trying to create a template page for projects: this can be simply done by creating a file inside `/templates` folder. A simple component like this should work:

```
const Projects = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Wrapper></Wrapper>
    </Layout>
  );
};


export const Head = () => <title>Our Projects</title>

export default Projects
```

This template, as long as you use it when creating pages (using either `gatsby-node.js` or [File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/)) will be used to hold each specific project data.

Each project data will be queried using GraphQL and held inside `props.data` but without knowing your source (can be markdown, JSON, CMS, etc) I can't provide a sample query.

Once Gatsby infers its GraphQL nodes from your data source, you can use it to get all projects, a specific project, or any other GraphQL data you need on any page/template ([page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/)) or even using [static queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/#usestaticquery).

The idea should be similar to:

```
// gatsby-node.js
projects.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
  createPage({
    path: node.fields.slug,
    component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/project.js`),
    context: {
      title: node.title, 
    },
  })
})
```

In your `gatsby-node.js` (or File System Route API) you get all projects, loop through them and `createPage` for each project. The path (URL) for each project will be the `slug` field (`node.fields.slug`) but you can use whatever you want. Gatsby will create dynamic pages based on this field.

Then you decide which component will be used as a template: `` path.resolve(`./src/templates/project.js`) `` in this case and finally, you populate the context to add a unique value (`title` in this case: again, this can be an `id`, the `slug`, etc). This value will be used to filter the node in the template.

In your `Project` template:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query ($title: String) {
    mdx(title: {eq: $title}) {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`
```

In this case, I'm using markdown-based sources (that's why the `mdx` node) and this node is filtered by the title (`$title`) using the context value. The data will be inside `props.data` of the template. Again, if you want to fetch all projects you will have available an `allMarkdown` or `allMdx` (or `allJSON`...) depending on the source node)